# Как сделать сложный блок в CSS

Tags: css, css3, блок

Как сделать такой блок, это делается в CSS или с помощью картинки? Причем чтобы там можно было размещать блоки. Если CSS то как?[image: "стрельчатый" блок]

Comment: как бы в html хоть лопни всё равно не важно что это прямоугольник или квадрат ...для чего  этот головняк ?

Comment: Можно и на чистом `css` (не целесообразно), лучше `svg`.. В зависимости от конечного результата и `canvas`, ну или просто картинка... Все зависит от желаемого конечного результата...

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вот способ извращения.

```css
body{
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-content{
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-content::before, .main-content::after{
  z-index: -3;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform:translate(-50%, -1167px) scaleX(10.0)  rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #34495E;
}

.main-content::before{
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="main-content">
  <h2>Кастомные фильтры в CSS</h2>
  <p>Встроенные CSS фильтры предлагают функционал, схожий с фильтрами в редакторах изображений — у вас        сет предустановленных, повсеместно используемых эффектов, в которых вы можете только контролировать      параметры.
  </p>
</section>
</body>
```